# how do I make a function where i have three str values and based on the third str it prints the letters of str1 and str2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a function:

```
def chars(str1: str, str2: str, str3: str) -> str:
```

What should I put inside this so that it returns a new string where the character at index i is
str1[i] if str3[i] is 0 and str2[i] if str3[i] is 1.

for example, if I had:

```
chars('dog', 'cat', '001')
```

it would output:

```
dot #since the first 0 is d from str1, the second 0 is o from str1 and the 1 is t from str2
```

Another example could be:

```
chars('army', 'game', '0011')
```

it would output:

```
arme ##since the first 0 is a from str1, the second 0 is r from str1, the first 1 is m from str2 and the second 1 is e from str2
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
for i in range(len(str3)):
    if str3[i] == '0':
        return str1[i]
    else:
        return str2[i]
```

but it only returns the first letter and nothing else so how would I fix this?

Comment: Rather than *returning* `str1[i]` or `str2[i]` -- tack them onto a growing string which you then return after the loop. If you are in the mood for a one-liner you could also just do `return ''.join(a if c == '0' else b for a,b,c in zip(str1,str2,str3))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code can be fixed by adding a variable

```py
def chars(str1: str, str2: str, str3: str) -> str:
    final = "" # I added a variable with name final
    for i in range(len(str3)):
        if str3[i] == '0':
            final += str1[i]
        else:
            final += str2[i]
    return final
    
print(chars("dog", "cat", "001")) # For testing purpose
```

Here the code goes as follows
final = ""

1. str3[0] = 0 so
   final = final + str1[0] -> final = "d"
2. str3[1] = 0 so
   final = final + str1[1] -> final = "do"
3. str3[2] = 1 so
   final = final + str2[2] -> final = "dot"
   return final -> "dot"

Answer (score 0):

I think following function does the expected output, try it and let's know:

```py
def chars(str1: str, str2: str, str3: str) -> str:
    out=str1[:(len(str1)-1)]
    out+=str2[-1:]
    out=''.join(out)
    
    return out
```